# Cloudflare and cPanel 'Deliverability Checker' both indicate SPF & DKIM records are valid but spam checkers insist the records don't exist. Thoughts?

Tags: email, cloudflare, shared-hosting, spf, dkim

Getting support for this issue is tricky since my DNS provider can't see my hosting info and my hosting provider can't see my DNS record configuration. I'm hoping that some DNS record pros can help me out. Here is the prerequisite information.

- The domain in question is owned by me. Website is hosted by
  Hostgator— shared hosting for a single domain with Wordpress web app.
  So nothing is hosted locally.
- Cloudflare is the primary DNS provider. I have A, CNAME, MX, DKIM,
  SPF, and DMARC records configured there.

I assumed that DNS provision was an all-or-nothing type of deal. However, cPanel indicates the existence of a valid PTR record that I know nothing about so I guess I was wrong. I also saw in cPanel that my mail server uses Mail HELO to identify itself as "wp1234.hostgator.com" when sending mail from my domain. I suspect this has something to do with the problem but I don't know.

**Current DNS record configuration:**

**MX:** My MX record specifies the mail server domain that is authorized to handle incoming mail for my domain. Let's call that mail.mysite.com.

**A:** I have two 'A' records. One for the root domain mysite.com, and one for mail.mysite.com for the purpose of translating the 'mail' subdomain into the corresponding mail server IP address '108.123.456.78'. The root 'A' record is proxied through Cloudflare, the mail 'A' record is set to DNS only and is *not* proxied.

**SPF:** My SPF record specifies the mail server IP address as the sole authority in sending emails on my behalf, denying all other senders:

> v=spf1 +ip4:108.123.456.78 -all

I originally included the Mail HELO domain in the record like this:

> v=spf1 +ip4:108.123.456.78 include:wp1234.hostgator.com -all

However, Cloudflare returned a warning, claiming that my SPF record exceeds the maximum allotment of 10 lookups, which makes sense since it's a hostgator subdomain. Since I have no way of accessing the records for that HELO domain I removed the 'include' from the spf record. I suspect that this has something to do with the problem as there is nothing in any of my DNS records providing for wp1234.hostgator.com even though it's masquerading as my mail server so you'd think there should be something. To be honest, I'm not sure what the purpose of the HELO is. Anyway, from this point on you'll start to see a rapid decline in my knowledge of this stuff and it will become clear that I have no idea what I'm doing.

**DKIM:** The spam checkers are also claiming that there's no valid DKIM entry in my records. For this one I just copy and pasted exactly what cPanel told me.

> Name: default._domainkey
> Value: v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=long-ass-public-key

Obviously replace "long-ass-public-key" with my actual long-ass public key. There should also be a private key that goes with that. Supposedly it's somewhere in the backend of my site but I have no idea where it is or if it even exists. The "default._domainkey" part, I'm not obfuscating that one at all. That's exactly what cPanel told me to write. Verbatim. I've heard, from many sources, that the 'Name' entry should also include the root domain at the end, followed by one last dot like this:

> Name: default._domainkey.mysite.com.

I figured I'd try doing that to see if it made any difference but when I do, the end part (.mysite.com.) disappears as soon as I save the changes. Cloudflare doesn't throw an error up or offer an explanation or anything, it just slaps it away like a goalie.

Alright, that's about it. For thoroughness, I should probably add that I also have one CNAME record for 'www' and one DMARC record configured as per cPanel's instruction.

**Other settings & suspect behavior:**

In my Cloudflare dashboard I have DNSSEC, Multi-signer DNSSEC, and CNAME flattening enabled even though I have no idea what they do. They just sounded like more security so I checked them. CNAME flattening shows "Flattening CNAME at apex" whatever that means. The Multi-Signer DNSSEC shows as enabled with no errors or messages. DNSSEC shows as pending with the following message:

> "DNSSEC is pending while we wait for the DS to be added to your
> registrar. This usually takes ten minutes, but can take up to an hour"

That message has been there for two weeks.

That's everything. I'm hoping someone sees this and knows exactly what to do. If any further information is needed let me know. Thanks for reading, I appreciate the help.

-Morgan

Comment: Please share your domain name, so that I can launch a few external diagnostics

Comment: @LuisAlbertoBarandiaran https://deviantla.com

Comment: SPF & DKIM seems ok. DMARC record is incomplete. Try changing it to the following, and let me know if it fixes your issue: v=DMARC1; p=reject; sp=reject; fo=1; aspf=s; adkim=s; pct=100; rua=mailto:369c17b7d8c741d8a38917d8459b7605@dmarc-reports.cloudflare.net

Comment: Cool. Okay, I'll give it a shot. Is the theory behind this to set the DMARC policy very strict to ensure the SPF and DKIM are checked and enforced?

Comment: I got an error/warning from the MxToolBox tool, so that change should fix at least that message. If the problem persists, tell me which tool are you using that tells you it's misconfigured so that I can try to replicate the scenario.

Comment: "spam checkers insist".....what spam checkers? And you've given no indication of timings here. DNS changes need to propagate.

Comment: SOLVED. I had to include 'websitewelcome.com' in the spf record. Apparently everything is routed through there. @LuisAlbertoBarandiaran I appreciate you taking the time to help. It wasn't a complete waste because I'm going to keep that dmarc policy

Comment: You might need to reconsider having websitewelcome.com as an include in your SPF record. It causes 10 DNS lookups by itself. So now your SPF record is broken for having 11 DNS lookups. The easy fix would be to drop the `MX` mechanism, unless that host is actually sending emails. But having 10 lookups (websitewelcome.com) is still a risk and a terrible mistake to ask clients to include your record like that.